# IP to IP forwarding with iptables [centos]

Tags: centos, iptables, linux-networking, forwarding

I have 2 servers. Server 1 with ip 1.1.1.1 and server 2 with ip 2.2.2.2

My domain example.com points to 1.1.1.1 at the moment, but very soon I'm going to switch to ip 2.2.2.2. I have already setup a low TTL for domain example.com, but some people will still hit the old ip a after I change the ip address of the domain.

Now both machines run centos 5.8 with iptables and nginx as a webserver.

I want to forward all traffic that still hits server 1.1.1.1 to 2.2.2.2 so there won't be any downtime.

Now I found this tutorial: http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-a-new-ip-using-iptables but I cannot seem to get it working.

I have enabled ip forwarding: `echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

After that I ran these 2 commands:

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:80
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

But when I load `http://1.1.1.1` in my browser, I still get the pages hosted on 1.1.1.1 and not the content from 2.2.2.2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `-s 1.1.1.1` to `-d 1.1.1.1`

You want to match the destination address and not the source address...

You also need to adjust your MASQUERADE-rule to include the interface the traffic takes on the way back. (Most likely eth0 or similar).

Do this with the -o flag. For example like this:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

Comment: Just tried that, but unfortunately no change :(

Comment: Hm, could the problem be that you haven't defined the out-interface in your MASQUERADE-rule?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: I've added some information to my reply now @FunkyChicken.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two machines in the same subnet and can reach each other without going through other routers? If not, the method described won't work even if you set it up properly.

When doing such migrations, I often use [rinetd](http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/) to forward random TCP ports. Or Apache's mod_proxy, if you use Apache anyways (which you do not, but I do).